# some files on SD card show up as 0 byte on Win10

Tags: external-sd, 7.0-nougat, mtp

I have a Samsung S7 (Android 7.0), with an encrypted SD card. I copied 3 mkv files via FTP on it. I can play all 3 on the phone without any problem.

When I plugged the phone in my Win10 laptop, only the first file showed the correct size in File Explorer. The other two seem to be 0 bytes, even when I copy them to my HDD.

If I copy these files from the SD to the internal storage of the phone, the file size is shown correctly, and the copied files are usable.

How can this be, how can I correct this behavior?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it's encrypted